# Memory Optimisation Flutter

Tags: flutter, image-optimization, memory-optimization

I am developing an app which asks the user to choose from a list of images from their gallery. Once the user chooses a list of images I render it on the screen for further use cases. I am currently using the image picker package to allow the user to selects multiple images.
Since the image picker creates a temp cahce folder where it stores the image I decided to copy the images to an app directory (so that when the user updates the app the images will not be lost). But the problem with this is that it increases the app size drastically. One way I thought of doing is to use the path where the image is stored in the phones directory rather than copying it within the app, but have no idea on how to achieve this.
If you have an idea or even a better approach please help me out !!